# Remove Multiple Polygon On google Map Objective C

Tags: ios

I am developing Iphone app and using Google map.Draw Multiple Polygon on google Map. but than deleting the polygon on map that deleting the last polygon not delete all draw polygon on google map.please help thanks in advance.

```
code..
// Draw Polygon

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    if (buttonClicked == true) {
        NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
        _latLongDict = @{@"lat":@(coordinate.latitude), @"long":@(coordinate.longitude)};
        [_clickCoordinate addObject:_latLongDict];
        NSLog(@"%@",_clickCoordinate);

        _path = [GMSMutablePath path];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D event;

        for (NSDictionary *dic in _clickCoordinate) {
            event.latitude = [[dic valueForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
            event.longitude = [[dic valueForKey:@"long"] floatValue];
            [_path addCoordinate:event];
        }
        _polygun = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:_path];
        _polygun.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
        _polygun.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _polygun.strokeWidth = 2;
        _polygun.map = mapView;
       }

// Delete Polygon

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender {
    for (int i = 0; i < _path.count; i++) {
        _polygun.map = nil;
        [_clickCoordinate  removeAllObjects];
        [_path removeAllCoordinates];
        NSLog(@"%@",_clickCoordinate);
    }
}
```

Comment: `_polygun.map = nil;` is enough to not shows polygons on map!!

Comment: _polygun.map = nil; delete only last polygon not delete all draw polygun

Comment: @DeepakKumar Are you having any thing else than `Polygon` in your mapView like annotation or overlay or something else? Means on your map you are just having only polygons nothing else.

Comment: @DeepakKumar You haven't inform that your map only contains polygon or you are showing marker also on your map ?

Comment: i can show marker and polygon on same map